# Constant with same name in different Unit in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi 6. I have created a project and added two unit `Unit1` and `Unit2`in it.
 I have a constant named `XML_DIAGRAM='Diagram_Data'` as a constant for XML node, I have also declared the same constant in the unit `Unit2`but with different value 'Diagram_Name' and I am using both the unit in main unit.
My question is that when I access constant `XML_DIAGRAM` it always contain value of constant from unit `Unit2`.
 If the constant with same name is declared in multiple unit then how Delphi decide from which unit the constant to take when user make request?

My Code:

```
unit Unit1;   
const
DIAGRAM = 'Diagram_Data';   
end.
```

```
 unit Unit2;         
 const
 DIAGRAM = 'Diagram_Name';       
 end.
```

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs,Unit1,Unit2;
```

Comment: I don't know that much about Delphi (and forgot most of my Pascal knowledge) but can't you prefix the name with the unit-name? Like `Unit1.DIAGRAM` and `Unit2.DIAGRAM`? [This tutorial about scoping](http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/l/aa060899.htm) seems to indicate that anyway.

Comment: I can't say for sure why Unit2 takes precedence but possibly because it is loaded after Unit1 by the IDE so Unit2's declaration supersedes Unit1's.  In any case, this is a terrible convention, to duplicate the name of a constant in shared units. Why not call them XML_DIAGRAM_NAME and XML_DIAGRAM_DATA?

Comment: Yes we can use this way, but I want to know how delphi decide which constant to use, shouldn't it raise a complie time error for this, that constant with same name is used in the unit, something like that.

Comment: @Rahul - It decides as [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Programs_and_Units#Multiple_and_Indirect_Unit_References).

Comment: Thanks @ Sertac Akyuz. I will try to understand it.

Comment: @Rahul: This is typical of Pascal: a "later" declaration will hide the "earlier" declaration. This is not an error, it is as designed. To access the "earlier" declaration, simply qualify it with the unit name, like J__ proposed: `Unit1.DIAGRAM`. But I agree with him too that you should use different names.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Pascal doesn't have units, and you can only have multiple declarations with the same name when you have units. In Pascal, you cannot have multiple declarations with the same name. Perhaps you are talking about some variant of Pascal.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: AFAIK, in ISO Pascal, you could even have the same function name in the same program twice. It was typical for Pascal. This may have changed in later versions, but it was so in the version with which I learned Pascal. This was documented too.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis ISO Pascal specification is here http://www.pascal-central.com/docs/iso7185.pdf and section 6.2 seems to contradict your statement

Comment: @David: that is too new. Many things have changed since then (early nineteen eighties).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis So when you said "ISO Pascal" you meant something else that is not ISO Pascal. I don't think there's much to be gained from us continuing this discussion here.

Comment: I meant the ISO Pascal I learnt. The standard seems to have changed since then.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I very much doubt that. It would be most odd to allow multiple identifiers with the same name to be defined in the same scope. I think your are mis-remembering.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am not misremembering. It is the very reason why I was not surprised that identifiers in different units could hide other identifiers, when Turbo Pascal 4 came out. The ISO Pascal I had did not have units.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If the constant with same name is declared in multiple unit then how Delphi decide from which unit the constant to take when user make request?

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Programs_and_Units#Multiple_and_Indirect_Unit_References) explains how this scenario is treated:

> The order in which units appear in the uses clause determines the order of their initialization and affects the way identifiers are located by the compiler. **If two units declare a variable, constant, type, procedure, or function with the same name, the compiler uses the one from the unit listed last in the uses clause.** (To access the identifier from the other unit, you would have to add a qualifier: UnitName.Identifier.)

So, in the scenario in the question, `DIAGRAM` refers to the symbol defined in `Unit2`. That's because the uses clause lists the units in the order `Unit1, Unit2` and `Unit2` is listed last. If you reverse the order in the `uses` clause, `Unit2, Unit1`, then `DIAGRAM` refers to the symbol defined in `Unit1`.

The documentation also shows how to use fully qualified names to be explicit about which symbol you want. You would write `Unit1.DIAGRAM` or `Unit2.DIAGRAM`.

One final point to make is that using the same name in different units is something of a recipe for confusion. You would be well-advised to find a way to write your code to avoid this.